# Express.js app working locally but failing to deploy on Netlify/Vercel/Render despite following documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel, netlify

I have a server.js file

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: 'config.env' });
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('./app');
// connection do DB
const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<password>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    dbName: 'JSQuiz',
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log('DB connection successful!'));

const port = process.env.PORT;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "description": "Server for Vue app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

working app.js (a lot of code hidden):

```
const homeRouter = require('./routes/homeRoutes');
const routers = [...homeRouter...]
routers.forEach(router => {
  app.use('/api/v1', router);
});
```

I have a express.js app that works just fine. But i cant deploy it to work on netlify/vercel/render, after following their docs and tutorials. So i guess my code is the problem. I tried to use different deploying platforms that should be easy, but hosting a express app is harder than i thought. But my code is pretty simple, but i cant figure out why it doesnt work. Do you see the problem?

Comment: whats the error you get during deployment?

Comment: 404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND- vercel

404- netlify

render, just doesnt work..